# serverless framework throws "Execution logs are not supported on protocolType http" when using ApiGatewayV2

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to create a http end point to trigger my lambda function (and potentially later integrate with fire hose). In my serverless.yml I have turned execution logs off for my ApiGatewayV2 by turning setting it to off as such

```
    Stage:
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
      Properties:
        ApiId: 
          Ref: Api
        DeploymentId: 
          Ref: Deployment
        StageName: v1
        DefaultRouteSettings:
          LoggingLevel: OFF
          DataTraceEnabled: true
```

and additionally I have also tried turning of execution logging for the lambda function it triggers like this

```
functions:
  StreamFunction:
    memorySize: 128
    runtime: rust
    handler: hello
    role: StreamRole
    logs:
      executionLogging: false
      fullExecutionData: false
```

but I keep getting the following error: 'Execution logs are not supported on protocolType http' is this a bug or are there any additional places I have to explicitly turn logs off

Comment: Do you use the http event as a part of the function definition? You really do not need to get explicit with the API Gateway configuration. Just assigning an http event should be enough

Comment: Yes I have previously used the http event and that works fine but I'm looking to use ApiGatewayV2  to to trigger a Fire hose delivery as well and i belive that would require me being specific especially around the ApiGatewayV2.integration.integrationURI and were also wanting to do something more specific with the   ApiGatewayV2.integration.RequestTemplates. if there is a way of automating all of this outside of the resources section though that would be ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTraceEnabled` is only supported for WebSocket APIs.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apigatewayv2-stage-routesettings.html.  Since you mention the API you are creating is an HTTP endpoint, setting `DataTraceEnabled: false` or removing the `DataTraceEnabled` option from your template should fix this error.